# PowerPoint VBA "File not found" (error 53), but file does exist

Tags: vba, rss, powerpoint, file-not-found

I am working on a VBA enabled PowerPoint that gets a feed from rssweather.com and parses it to find the current weather (As of the current state, it does not do so yet.) So far, I use `getPageText` to get the the feed as a XML file and then begin parsing it (Occasionally, there is an index error while parsing. I am currently looking into this, but it is not related to the question I am posting). I wanted to have a text document that contains a feed to compare to the incoming feed and check for a format changes (as this would throw off the parser). My problem is when I try to get the contents of the file, VBA cannot find it (it is located in the same directory as the PowerPoint. I have done some reading and here are some of the things I have tried other people have had problems with 
-moving the file to a different location and trying the new filepath
-checking for hidden or read only attibutes
-checking for typos in the filepath (I tried cutting and pasting from file explorer)
-checking for escape/special characters in the filepath
-making sure the file is not on a network drive (I am RDP-ing into the PC to work on the powerpoint, but the files are stored on it's desktop)
-trying someone else's working code
-checking access permissions
-adding a backslash before the filename (functions that return the working directory do not do so for you)

Here is my code that gets the feed:

```
Function getPageText(url As String) 'this function is used to get webpage data. in our Macro, it gets the current weather from www.rssweather.com
    Dim waited As Integer 'used to see if webpage is responding
    Dim temp 'this variable is involved when seeing i the webpage is done downloading

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url
        .send

        'get the text
        On Error GoTo Retry
        getPageText = .responseText 'return as one massive string
    End With

    'attempt to use webpage and catch with error
Retry:
    'bump up waited for entering
    waited = waited + 1

    'check for timeout
    If waited = 30 Then GoTo No_connection 'if no response after 30 seconds, display error

    'no timeout so try again
    On Error GoTo Retry
    Counters.Wait (1)
    temp = getPageText

    Exit Function

No_connection:
    MsgBox "Error: RSS feed timed out. Please check the connection or contact your local VBA expert."

    'kill the timers
    Call KillOnTime

    'set the function to nothing so WeatherUpdate will recogize it as an error in the rss feed format checking
    getPageText = ""

End Function
```

Here is my code that is supposed to compare and parse the feed:

```
Sub WeatherUpdate()

'setup variables to represent the textboxes actual fields for ease of use
Dim curr As String
Dim fore As String
Dim img As String

curr = ""
fore = ""
img = ""

'get rss feed. getPageText returns the content in XML code as one massive string
Dim webcontent As String
webcontent = getPageText("http://www.rssweather.com/zipcode/24523/rss.php")

'verify rss feed is still using the same format CHECK LENGTH TOO
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim examplecontent As String

iFile = FreeFile
Open ActivePresentation.Path & "\Example RSS Feed.txt" For Input As iFile
examplecontent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close iFile

'Debug.Print examplecontent
'Debug.Print simil(examplecontent, webcontent)

'start scraping out the XML code and keep the text we want by using XML features
curr = curr & Split(Split(webcontent, "<title>")(2), "F")(0) & "ºF, " & Split(Split(webcontent, "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "sky" & Chr(34) & ">")(1), "<")(0) ' this grabs the text between <title> and </title> to use as current conditions title

img = Split(Split(Split(webcontent, "<img src=" & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0), "fcicons/")(1) 'this complicated splitting grabs the image name out of a webaddress so we know what icon/weather symbol they are trying to use so we can pick the same

webcontent = Right(webcontent, Len(webcontent) - Len(Split(webcontent, "<dd id=" & Chr(34))(0)) - 8) 'this shortens and simplifies the overall webcontent string by cutting out the beginning we took curr and img from

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Humidity: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(1), "<")(0) 'grab humidity value and pack it nicely into "Humidity: [value]"

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Windspeed: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(5), "<")(0) 'grab windspeed value

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Wind Direction: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(9), "(")(0) 'grab winddir value

'curr is now filled with what is needed. cut out the XML crap to skip to the next area
webcontent = Split(webcontent, "</guid>")(1)

'next, all forecast entries follow the same format. we will have to store them in a string array and refer to each area by index
Dim forecontent() As String
forecontent = Split(webcontent, "<item>")

'fill out the forecast for day+1 (index 3)


'start the timer to run again in an hour
'Call StartOnTime

End Sub
```

Here is my code all together for you

```
Option Explicit

Dim weatherImage As Shape 'this variable will hold the location of the weather slide's changing image
Dim weatherCurrent As Shape 'this variable will hold the location of the current weather text on the weather slide
Dim weatherForecast As Shape 'this variable will hold the location of the forecast text on the weather slide

'timer code. runs a sub every x miliseconds. retrieved from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/9f6891f2-d0c4-47a6-b63f-48405aae4022/powerpoint-run-macro-on-timer. Thanks for the help user SJOO!
Dim lngTimerID As Long
Dim blnTimer As Boolean

Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal _
    lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Sub StartOnTime()
    If blnTimer Then
        lngTimerID = KillTimer(0, lngTimerID)
        If lngTimerID = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error : Timer Not Stopped"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        blnTimer = False

    Else
        lngTimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, 3600000, AddressOf WeatherUpdate) 'modified from HelloTimer to Weather Update and timer length from 5 seconds (5000) to an hour (3600000)
        If lngTimerID = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error : Timer Not Generated "
            Exit Sub
        End If
        blnTimer = True

    End If
End Sub

Sub KillOnTime()
    lngTimerID = KillTimer(0, lngTimerID)
    blnTimer = False
End Sub
'end of timer code

Function getPageText(url As String) 'this function is used to get webpage data. in our Macro, it gets the current weather from www.rssweather.com
    Dim waited As Integer 'used to see if webpage is responding
    Dim temp 'this variable is involved when seeing i the webpage is done downloading

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url
        .send

        'get the text
        On Error GoTo Retry
        getPageText = .responseText 'return as one massive string
    End With

    'attempt to use webpage and catch with error
Retry:
    'bump up waited for entering
    waited = waited + 1

    'check for timeout
    If waited = 30 Then GoTo No_connection 'if no response after 30 seconds, display error

    'no timeout so try again
    On Error GoTo Retry
    Counters.Wait (1)
    temp = getPageText

    Exit Function

No_connection:
    MsgBox "Error: RSS feed timed out. Please check the connection or contact your local VBA expert."

    'kill the timers
    Call KillOnTime

    'set the function to nothing so WeatherUpdate will recogize it as an error in the rss feed format checking
    getPageText = ""

End Function

Function charAt(str As String, index As Integer)

charAt = CChar(Mid(str, index, 1))

End Function

Function simil(str1 As String, str2 As String) 'this function returns the percent similar two strings are. this is used to determine if the rss feed has had a format change

'total number of similar characters
Dim total As Long

'str1 should be the shortest, switch them if they are not
If Len(str1) >= Len(str2) Then
Dim temp As String
temp = str1
str1 = str2
str2 = temp

'iterate through the str1 and compare characters
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(str1)

If charAt(str1, i) = charAt(str1, i) Then
total = total + 1
End If

Next i

'return percent similar as a percent! aka already multiplied by 100
simil = total / Len(str2)

End Function

Sub weatherFind() 'this sub locates the weather slide and assigns weatherImage and weatherText to their respective location

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'2D loop to go through each slide and each image on the slide
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Count

If StrComp(ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j).Name, "weather_curr") = 0 Then
Set weatherCurrent = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j)
End If

If StrComp(ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j).Name, "weather_fore") = 0 Then
Set weatherForecast = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j)
End If

If StrComp(ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j).Name, "weather_img") = 0 Then
Set weatherImage = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j)
End If

Next j
Next i

'trigger the weather update now and every hour
Call WeatherUpdate

End Sub

Sub WeatherUpdate()

'setup variables to represent the textboxes actual fields for ease of use
Dim curr As String
Dim fore As String
Dim img As String

curr = ""
fore = ""
img = ""

'get rss feed. getPageText returns the content in XML code as one massive string
Dim webcontent As String
webcontent = getPageText("http://www.rssweather.com/zipcode/24523/rss.php")

'verify rss feed is still using the same format CHECK LENGTH TOO
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim examplecontent As String

iFile = FreeFile
Open ActivePresentation.Path & "\Example RSS Feed.txt" For Input As iFile
examplecontent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close iFile

'Debug.Print examplecontent
'Debug.Print simil(examplecontent, webcontent)

'start scraping out the XML code and keep the text we want by using XML features
curr = curr & Split(Split(webcontent, "<title>")(2), "F")(0) & "ºF, " & Split(Split(webcontent, "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "sky" & Chr(34) & ">")(1), "<")(0) ' this grabs the text between <title> and </title> to use as current conditions title

img = Split(Split(Split(webcontent, "<img src=" & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0), "fcicons/")(1) 'this complicated splitting grabs the image name out of a webaddress so we know what icon/weather symbol they are trying to use so we can pick the same

webcontent = Right(webcontent, Len(webcontent) - Len(Split(webcontent, "<dd id=" & Chr(34))(0)) - 8) 'this shortens and simplifies the overall webcontent string by cutting out the beginning we took curr and img from

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Humidity: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(1), "<")(0) 'grab humidity value and pack it nicely into "Humidity: [value]"

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Windspeed: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(5), "<")(0) 'grab windspeed value

curr = curr & vbCrLf & "Wind Direction: " & Split(Split(webcontent, ">")(9), "(")(0) 'grab winddir value

'curr is now filled with what is needed. cut out the XML crap to skip to the next area
webcontent = Split(webcontent, "</guid>")(1)

'next, all forecast entries follow the same format. we will have to store them in a string array and refer to each area by index
Dim forecontent() As String
forecontent = Split(webcontent, "<item>")

'fill out the forecast for day+1 (index 3)


'start the timer to run again in an hour
'Call StartOnTime

End Sub
```

And here's proof that the file actually exists:

[playing hide and seek with Example RSS Feed.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lFqK.png)

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Did you solve it? Code works fine for me - even with the same filename. Maybe there is a problem with rights? Try to put the file somewhere outside the \User area in a simple folder (D:\testarea)

Comment: I never solved it, just approached the problem from a different angle so I did not need to open any files. Also, I did try moving the file around and got the same error. Thanks Though!

Answer (score 0):

Without looking in detail your code, maybe just try opening your file through the vba script. The [limited MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-not-found-error-53) tells us that either your filepath doesn't bring you to the file.

I would try to spy this variable to see if the string output is the right path:

```
ActivePresentation.Path & "\Example RSS Feed.txt" For Input As iFile
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have already tried verifying the filepath. I used 
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Path & "\Example RSS Feed.txt"
 and copied/pasted it into file explorer and it brought me to the text file. it even opened it for me.